# iOS -Objective C- Prevent the keyboard automatically hide when I set enable = NO on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm working on an App with Objective-C  but I have a problem with my form.

I have several inputs view (UITextField) on it, and one with a particularly behavior.

When I select the checkbox, I prevent the user typing on the view and looks the view as disable( grayed out and without the blue bar flashing blue bar ) and keep the keyboard open.

When I set the UITextField as disable, the keyboard is automatically hidden.

**Someone knows how to keep the keyboard open?**

I need to something like the image attached, but without the blue bar flashing blue bar.

[image]

I did the logic to prevent the the user enter data on the input , but the keyboard is automatically hidden.

Comment: why would you keep the keyboard open if you can't type anywhere, that's confusing for users...

Comment: Because, the form is an horizontal form, and we use the button "Continuar" / "Anterior" to move to the next or previous input on the form. If we close the keyboard the user maybe will not be able to do that. What do you think ?

Comment: Rather to disable keyboard you can use following method and return no When check box is checked.  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

Comment: Thanks for the response !! , one question if I do that, the flashing blue bar  will disappear ?

Comment: I agree with others, sounds like you are trying to achieve a very bad design for your users. I'm struggling to understand why you need to do this, let alone how to. If its possible to continue without entering a number, then simply make the field optional, don't require a value to continue. There is no need to force the user to lock the textfield. Part of good design, especially for mobile, is learning to do something in as few clicks / taps as possible. I see no reason for that checkbox at all

Comment: You are right, I thought the same. But I have two problems:
1 ) The api of my app needs the string "SN", in the case where I select the checkbox. You can say, "No problem, send it when you make the request", I'm agree with you, but here there is the second problem:
2) The UX guys want that I show the SN string on the input and the keyboard open. :(

Answer (score 0):

If the text field is disabled, the user cannot type into it and the dismissal of the keyboard is correct. You should not try to fight against that. (It sounds like you're trying to disable the keyboard for the wrong reasons anyway.)

In this case, it sounds like your timing is just off. When the user clicks the checkbox, your code responds. What you are doing there is just wrong. You should respond by *moving the first responder* to the next enabled text field *yourself*, and *then* disabling the first text field. That way, you are not disabling the text field while it is first responder; that's your whole mistake right there.

Comment: Ok, Thanks !! I'm trying do that, because on the form the user uses the buttons "Continuar" / "Anterior" to move to the next or previous input on the form. As you said, maybe the decision for disable the input view is wrong. What do you suggest to do ? I need to keep the keyboard open, but the input view without the blue bar flashing blue

Comment: I don't see what those buttons have to do with anything. If you want the buttons to make the user move to the next text field, do that. I have buttons that do that sort of thing myself. But that has nothing to do with hiding the keyboard, and is _not what you asked_. I answered what you asked, I believe. If the question is how to implement those "next" and "previous" buttons, then that is what you should have asked.

Comment: You are rigth, those buttons are related to the question; but I need it. Basically, this is the problem I need : to keep open the keyboar after I select the checkbox

Comment: -keep open the keyboard after I select the checkbox.
-"Hide" bar flashing blue, that indicates to you (user) can enter data on the input.
- Make the input looks like a disable (grayed out).
I have done the last two requirements, but when I mark it as disable (enable = NO), the keyboard is automatically hidden. I need to prevent that. 
- Make the input looks like a disable (grayed out).
I have done the last two requieres, but when I mark it as disable (enable = NO), the keyboard is automatically hidden. I need to prevent that.

Comment: When the user clicks the checkbox, _move the first responder_ to the next enabled text field _yourself_. And _then_ disable the first text field. That way, you are not disabling the text field while it is first responder; that's your whole mistake right there.